# How do I output my leaflet map from R into a Sharepoint site

Tags: html, r, sharepoint, r-leaflet

I created a leaflet map using R, saved as a webpage (html) on a local folder. My organization has a sharepoint site, and I'd like to host the map on a sharepoint site/page, so that people in my organization can interact with it.
How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an IFRAME to embed html in any site.

Take a look at this information below as a guide.

1. https://blog.mydock365.com/how-to-use-embed-web-part-in-sharepoint-online?hs_amp=true
2. https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-embed-content-from-other-websites-in-sharepoint-online/
3. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-content-to-your-page-using-the-embed-web-part-721f3b2f-437f-45ef-ac4e-df29dba74de8

Thanks